# Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in Title from the exams2nops function in R/Exams

Tags: r-exams

I am using the `exams` package and function `exams2nops`. My code is:

```
exams2nops(file=quests,
           n=1,
           nsamp = 1,
           intro = "\\includepdf[pages=-]{D:/OneDrive - ISPA/AEI/2022-2023/Exams/exam1/Intro.pdf}",
           language = "pt-PT",
           institution = "Análise Estatística I",
           title = "Época Recurso ---")
```

I get the error "! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (áli)"...

If I remove the accented character "à", "í" and "É"... then everything works with no errors. The quest exercices have a lot of accented characters and those print out fine. It just in the exam2nops title and institution that I get the error!....

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In which encoding did you store your code ?

Comment: My encoding is UTF-8

Comment: My guess is that your R session is not UTF-8 and hence the string does not get encoded correctly. On my machine I cannot replicate this (which is running in UTF-8). Three possible workarounds: (1) Switch to a UTF-8 encoding in your session. (2) Use LaTeX escapes for the non-ASCII characters, i.e., `"{\\'E}poca Recurso ---"`. (3) Possibly storing the script and `source()`-ing it may work.

Comment: My default text encoding is UTF-8 (set in Rstudio > Options >Code > Saving >Default text encoding: UTF-8). I also saved the Rmd where I call the `exams2nops` function as UTF-8.  Using `"{\\'E}poca Recurso ---"` does work. Another workaround is `title=tangram::latex(Época Recurso ---")`.  This strange UTF-8 problem only occurs in `exams2nops`. `exams2pdf` works fine with `title = " Época de Recurso ---"`. Finally, my colleague @jsinval runs this same file in a ubuntu machine and no problem at all with ´"É" or other accented characters.

Comment: I played around with this some more, still cannot replicate the problem. Maybe you can run your code and additionnally set the argument `texdir = "/path/to/empty/directory"`. Then you can inspect the .tex files that are created in that temporary folder. Not that it should be empty before calling `exams2nops()` so that nothing of importance can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks!... I did find the tex files in the temp directories. When tried to compile it with TexEditor, the same error. The "É" character does not get corrected translated. After correction, the tex file compiled ok.  The strange thing is that the error only occrus with `exams2nops` not with `exams2pdf`.

Comment: Please inspect the tex files from the temp directories: Why do they lead to an error? You say that the "É" does not get correctly translated. Can you find out why that happens? Is the tex file in a different encoding? Is there something else instead of the "É" in the file? I need you to do the debugging here because I cannot replicate the error on my end.